# How to get autocompletion for custom annotations (tags) in PhpStorm

Tags: php, autocomplete, annotations, phpstorm, phpdoc

I am in the process of writing custom tags in order to provide association of methods with specified labels, and use that association later for whichever purposes. Something like this:

```
/**
 * @components login_form, header
 */
public function foo()
{
    // ...
}
```

But obviously it would be neater to store the labels as constants, so that it would look like this:

```
/**
 * @components Components::LOGIN_FORM, Components::HEADER
 */
public function foo()
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, I can tweak the used annotation processor to recognize and substitute the constants with their values, but the problem is that **PhpStorm doesn't provide autocompletion for custom tags**, like it does for `@var`, for example, which makes using constants not really convenient.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be [not possible at the moment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/797164).

For all those interested, you can vote for the [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9163).